# My published CrystalReports desktop app (VB.NET) wont run without installed CRforVS on the clients computer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

The published program run correctly on my developer computer, but wont run on the client computer without the CrystalReports SDK (CRforVS). The CR runtime is installed, but dont solved the problem.

The CR SDK needs an installed Visual Studio (VS) on the target computer, but I dont want setup theese programs (VS, CRforVS) on the clients computer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Windows Event Log, and find a FileNotFoundException.
After debugged the code in developer environment (VS) on the client computer, I found the concrete message:
"log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"

The solution is for the problem, that I set the Target CPU from "AnyCPU" to "x64" on Compile tab in the Project Properties in the VS.

Now it works fine!

[image]

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works.  Just to provide some more information, when you have your project's target CPU set to AnyCPU and the project includes Crystal Reports, you will need to install both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the CR Runtimes.  If you only had one of the runtime versions installed, your error was likely due to the missing runtime version.